# process finished with exit code -1073741515 - Mongo DB C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake

I have built mongocxx driver as per the installation given in the official site and have got .lib files for both mongocxx and bscon. I have linked those to my CMakeLists.txt file and no build errors. Linked perfectly to my current project and able to include mongo db headers and write code.

I tried connecting to my mongodb (instance running on localhost) from my C++ code which built successfully but while running no output it didnt even get into main function of my code.

IDE CLion shows the below error

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

I guess am missing something or wrote something wrong in my CMakeLists.txt, given below is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(enabler_app)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(enabler_app ${EXECUTABLES}
        )

add_library(MONGOCXX SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MONGOCXX PROPERTIES IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mongo_db_driver/lib/mongocxx.lib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mongo_db_driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} MONGOCXX)

add_library(BSONCXX SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(BSONCXX PROPERTIES IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mongo_db_driver/lib/bsoncxx.lib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mongo_db_driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} BSONCXX)
```

After linking mongocxx and bsoncxx only my application is not running and getting exit code.
My main.cpp is just printing hello world nothing else.

Help me, where am making mistake in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: This problem can probably be fixed by the response I provided to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61188219/3987854)... Did this suggestion not work for you? If not, what went wrong? What happens when you *also* fill out the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property?

Comment: I followed your suggestion for that question which solved my undefined reference issue and built successfully. Now if i try to run the program it exited with error code.

Comment: Based on the code in your question post, it doesn't look like you followed the suggestion. There is no `IMPORTED_LOCATION` mentioned anywhere in this code.

Comment: but I did not use IMPORTED_LOCATION which was throwing another error  when building and the error was `NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'MONGOCXX-NOTFOUND'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop`